# How to remove a specific series of characters from start of the url, if they exist

Tags: php, wordpress, url, path

I'm using a snippet to pull the URL path using `$_server[REQUEST_URI]`.

Now I need to remove this block from it (lang_code) if it exists at the beginning: `/en/`

I'm fairly under trained in PHP for this. What function should I use?

If I use the trim function it keeps trimming until it hits a character that's not in the list, therefore butchering URLs that start with e or n.

I expect the snippet to pull the URL Path, and trim only the beginning and only if it starts with `/en/` and only this block.

`/en/new-test-url/` > `new-test-url/`

The code I have now is:

```
<?php echo preg_replace("/" . preg_quote("/en/",'/') . "/", , '$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']'); ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add your code so people can better understand your question.

Comment: `echo substr($url, 4);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
$myStr = '/en/new-test-url/';

// for singlebyte strings
$result = substr($myStr, 0, 4);
// for multibyte strings
$result = mb_substr($myStr, 0, 4);

if($result == '/en/'){ 
   $result = substr($myStr, 4);  
}else{
   $result = $myStr;
}
echo $result;
```